# Working with XML using VB, getting error "Class cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of..."

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

I'm working with a web service using XML and VB and I'm trying to set up a query but I keep getting an error saying it can't be converted to a 1-dimensional array. In the class file there's the code comeing from the service:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Source", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Public Property POS() As SourceType()
    Get
        Return Me.pOSField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.pOSField = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And this is the code I'm setting up for the query:

```
rentalService.POS = New SourceType
```

and this gived me the error:

```
Value of type 'Service.SourceType' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Service.SourceType'
```

I'm still fairly new to VB and haven't working with XML or web services at all so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`rentalService.POS` is of type array of `SourceType` (`SourceType()`), and you assign it to a `SourceType` object instead of array here :

```
rentalService.POS = New SourceType
```

You need to initialize an array variable properly as explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx), for example :

```
rentalService.POS = New SourceType(5){} 'array size required to be know at init time
```

Comment: Adding an array size give new error "Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'."